# Background size depending on a letter height in CSS

Tags: css

Let's say I would like the yellow background to be 3 times higher as the size of the "M" letter. I've seen that as a question somewhere but don't know the trick. Any clue ? The html should not be change, only CSS must be added. Thanks.

```
<h1 class = "smth">My beautiful page</h1>

.smth{
color:blue;
background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `em` units for height of element. So if you set `font-size` of element to `20px` then `height` will be 3 times of that if you use `3em`

```css
h1{
  background: lightblue;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<h1 class = "smth">My beautiful page</h1>
```

Comment: If you want text in middle you can add some flexbox https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/449/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
height:2em;
```

or

```
.smth {
color:blue;
background-color: yellow;
height: 2em;
}
```

em is relative to the font-size of the element (2em means 2 times the size of the current font)

Comment: Thanks, it did helped.